# not able to query ISODate in mongodb through php

Tags: php, jquery, mongodb

I am implementing a search feature in which I need to filter records with start and end date. In my mongoDB,there is field called 'createdDate' which has date in ISODate format. 
I am picking up dates from users using jquery and In my php i have following code:

```
$mquery['createdDate']['$gte'][]=$startDate;  // 2018-07-13
$this->__mongo_collection->find($mquery)
```

MongoDb records look like this:
    {
        "team" : "abc",
        "createdDate" : ISODate("2018-03-08T08:22:07.000Z")
    }
Note : there are other fields also and for those search is working.

Comment: And the value in `$startDate` is what exactly? Also why should we take your word for how something is stored? If you have a problem, then give the people you are asking enough information to solve it. Show the value you are querying with and show the document you expect to match.

Comment: I have updated the description

Comment: Dates are not strings. There's a helper function in the library for casting dates.

Comment: How can we query date when its in string format, it has to be in some date format to compare between dates, right?

Comment: Your documents have BSON Dates. You need the PHP function to cast your "string" for query into a BSON Date. Shown in the duplicate question and answer.

Comment: As, per duplicate question, i am doing following :  $mquery['data.timestamp']['$gte'][]=strtotime($startDate);  but still no luck :(